# How do I deserialize an array of JSON objects to a C# anonymous type?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have no problem deserializing a single json object

```
string json = @"{'Name':'Mike'}";
```

to a C# anonymous type:

```
var definition = new { Name = ""};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);
```

But when I have an array:

```
string jsonArray = @"[{'Name':'Mike'}, {'Name':'Ben'}, {'Name':'Razvigor'}]";
```

I am stuck.

How can it be done?

Comment: You can deserialize it like a anonymous array: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonArray, new[] { new { Name = "" } });`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution is:

```
string json = @"[{'Name':'Mike'}, {'Name':'Ben'}, {'Name':'Razvigor'}]";

var definition = new[] { new { Name = "" } };

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);
```

Of course, since `result` is an array, you'll access individual records like so:

```
string firstResult = result[0].Name;
```

You can also call `.ToList()` and similar methods on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize to dynamic object by this.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonArray);
```

Comment: or like this 
        var result2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(jsonArray);

- You can acess it like 
        result2[0].Name

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to put an identifier in your JSON array string.

This code worked for me:

```
var typeExample = new { names = new[] { new { Name = "" } } };
string jsonArray = @"{ names: [{'Name':'Mike'}, {'Name':'Ben'}, {'Name':'Razvigor'}]}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonArray, typeExample);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way of ensure that `Name` or `Age` are the correct types? Or is that not applicable for anonymous types when deserialising json?